# How to plot the sum of something over an interval of time?

Tags: plotting

Say I have a dataframe with date as index. I would like to plot a line plot of some values in a column A over a given time frame. Say for the month of August. In column A I have several entries for example for the 02/08/2020 and a four different values on 03/08/2020 and so I would like to plot the sum of those values.

Is there an easy one line that would do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could aggregate and sum values in a single line by pandas `groupby()` function. Here's an example:

1. Making a simple dummy dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=50)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, columns=['values'])
```

2. Adding some dates as indices:

```py
def get_days():
    return sorted(np.random.choice(range(1, 31), size=25, replace=True))

year = '2021'
months = ['08', '09']
dates = []
for month in months:
    days = get_days()
    for day in days:
        dates.append(f'{day}/{month}/{year}')

df.index = dates
```

Dataframe looks like the following:

[image: head]

3. Aggregate and sum the data:

```py
answers = df.groupby(df.index, sort=False).sum()  # since index already sorted
```

Printing `answers`:

[image: head2]

4. Simply plot it

```py
dates = answers.index 
sums = answers.values 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(range(len(dates)), sums, 'ro-')
ax.set_xticks(range(0, len(dates), 3))       # need to adjust to ensure plot is readable
ax.set_xticklabels(dates[::3], rotation=90)
ax.set_xlabel("Dates")
ax.set_ylabel("Sums")
ax.set_title("Sum Over Dates")
plt.show();
```

The plot to the above code looks like the following:

[image: plot]

You can now control how you want to aggregate in several ways. You can add temporary columns as days, months, years and aggregate them hierarchically(and in a single line) if that is what you desire as shown [here](https://jamesrledoux.com/code/group-by-aggregate-pandas).

Plotting it in a single line will not only be difficult, but less readable too, so I'd suggest avoiding that.